# i want to when user change theme on outlook so instantly change color of task pane and window element like text box, label

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to when the user changes the theme in outlook so how to instantly change color of the task pane and window elements textbox, label etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

You can read the current Office theme in the following windows registry key:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Theme
```

where 15.0 stands for Office 2013 and means the Office version.

The values are:

Blue: 1

Silver: 2

Black: 3

Also Office applications send the `WM_MSO_BROADCASTCHANGE` message to their top level windows when the current theme is changed. You can register a window for receiving such message using the [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function provided by Windows API. See [WM_MSO_BROADCASTCHANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102389/wm-mso-broadcastchange-value) value for more information.